# Form validation: Error message not printing on submission of empty password field PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, passwords

I am attempting to validate a password field in a form. I would like to print the following message when the password is incorrect **OR** the field is empty:

> "Invalid, please try again."

I am able to get the message to print when the user guesses incorrectly. However, if the user clicks the submit button on the second attempt **AND** the field is empty (*or clicks the submit button on the first attempt*), **the form resets and the message disappears.**

Can anyone help here? Below is my code. Thx in advance.

```
    function printPw() {
      print<<<HERE
        <form method="post"
              action="">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password"
                   name="password"
                   id="password">
          <br>
          <input type="submit"
                 id="submit"
                 value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
HERE;
}

function checkpW() {
  global $password;
  if($password !== "cool" || $password == "") {
    print "INVALID, please try again.<br>\n";
    printPw();
  }
  else
    printForm();
}
```

Comment: What happens in `printForm();` exactly?

Comment: Unique validation!!..

Comment: And you are positive the `global $password` has been set

Comment: How do you set this variable ? `$password`

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia, there is no message input field. The message I am referring to is in the action of the if statement in the checkPw() function.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, the printForm() function prints a new form that allows user to submit content (i.e. guestbook comments).

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky $password is set in the checkPw() function, if I'm not mistaken. I'm still finding my sea legs so this could definitely be where my code is off.

Comment: Thanks @Joke_Sense10, but unique means nothing if the code doesn't work haha =/

Comment: But checkPW doesn't set it to any value. Will be somewhere else we cant see. Do you have any line like `$password=$_POST["password"]` ?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky extract($_REQUEST);

Comment: If I type 'cool' the password validates and the form prints. But if I click SUBMIT with an empty password field, the form resets.  If I've already received an 'INVALID' message for an incorrect attempt and I click the SUBMIT button again, the 'INVALID' message will disappear.